# How to performing clock with timing event in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I set up a clock with timing event and want to show in the html file. I have 2 files which are js and html file. js is to configure the clock with timing event and the html file is to show the timing.

My code is found below.
clock.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Clock with a timing event</title>
<script src="clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
    $(function () {
        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var min = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            var y = today.getFullYear();
            var mon = today.getMonth()+1;
            var d = today.getDate();
            min = checkTime(min);
            s = checkTime(s);
            mon = checkTime(mon);
            d = checkTime(d);
            document.getElementById('todaytime').innerHTML = " "+ d + "/" + mon + "/" +y + "  " + h + ":" + min + ":" + s + " SGT ";
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }
 });
```

The error states:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

My question is how to get the values from the js and show in the html file.

Comment: The `$ is undefined` error means you need to include jquery.js in the page

Comment: include the jquery library link

Comment: Darn it how stupid I am. Sigh.... I have been struggling this for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your current code:

- first one is that you never call the `startTime()` function anywhere therefore it never starts
- second one is that you are targeting an element with ID of `todaytime` while your HTML has an element with ID of `txt`
- third problem is the fact that your function is wrapped by a non-existent function (jQuery) so just remove the opening `$(function () {` and the last `}`

Here is the corrected code: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spd1tswo/1/)

Comment: thank for correcting my code, if i want to use jquery, then how to do it???

Comment: If you want to use jQuery then disregard the last issue I described and ensure you are including jQuery .js file within your page (i.e. using a `<script>` tag inside of your `<head>`) and that any code that depends on it (i.e. `clock.js`) is referenced _after_ you include jQuery - in your case you should change the order in which you include the two `<script>`s.

Comment: is the order in the two script necessary????

Comment: Yes, jQuery needs to be included before you start using jQuery